# Call back rest url using spring framework

Tags: spring, rest, asynchronous, publish-subscribe, asynccallback

I writing rest web services using spring framework 4.0 jars.
All the get calls and post are working fine.

I wanted to know how to implement an api which works asynchronously.
The client should post to this url and wait for the response ; something like call back mechanism between server and client . Server when gets the data posts response to this url.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring 4.0 framework has an easy solution to this.
Changed the Return type of the method DeferredResult .
Create an instance of  DeferredResult and assign whenever value is assigned to this instance it would return the response to calling request.

```
     @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public DeferredResult<String>  getNewMessage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        {
            DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<String>();
            processRequest(deferredResult);         
            return  deferredResult;
        }

void processRequest( DeferredResult<String> result)
{
result.setResult("hello world");
}
```